# INDIRECT function referring to a cell with text does not work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was looking at the official documentation of the INDIRECT function of Microsoft Excel [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). I have successfully duplicated most of the examples there except the third one, which is `=INDIRECT(A4)` where cell A4 contains the word "George".

After inserting `=INDIRECT(A4)` into my own excel sheet, the only text I got is `#REF!`. Refer picture below:

[image]

How can I get the value "10" by inserting `=INDIRECT(A4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "George" to refer to Cell B4, you should insert it as a name that refers to B4

Comment: you mean I should change the value of cell A4 to "B4"? But that would defeat the purpose of my question

Comment: No, you should assign the name George to cell B4